# JSF - Get HTML of UIComponent programmatically

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

How can I retrieve the HTML response of a single UIComponent programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "the HTML response"? You mean the markup that's generated by a component?

Comment: jep exactly, the final HTML that is send to the browser

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are already in a JSF request.

In that case you can set a custom response writer to the current FacesContext, for example a new `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter` and render the component afterwards:

```
public String createHtml(UIComponent component) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ResponseWriter oldWriter = context.getResponseWriter();
    try {
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
        context.setResponseWriter(new HtmlResponseWriter(buffer, "text/html", "UTF-8"));
        component.encodeAll(context);
        context.getResponseWriter().close();
        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        context.setResponseWriter(oldWriter);
    }
}
```

It's important to notice that your component or one of its children must not use any variables that are defined in another place on the page, as these variables are not defined if you just render the single component.

If you want to initialize all variables as well, you can print the HTML like the response to an AJAX request (partial response):

```
public String createHtml(UIComponent component) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ResponseWriter oldWriter = context.getResponseWriter();
    try {
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
        context.setResponseWriter(new HtmlResponseWriter(buffer, "text/html", "UTF-8"));

        final VisitContext vc = VisitContext.createVisitContext(context,
                Collections.singleton(component.getClientId()), 
                Collections.<VisitHint> emptySet());

        context.getViewRoot().visitTree(vc, new VisitCallback() {
            public VisitResult visit(final VisitContext ctx, final UIComponent comp) {
                try {
                    comp.encodeAll(ctx.getFacesContext());
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }

                return VisitResult.COMPLETE;
            }
        });
        context.getResponseWriter().close();
        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        context.setResponseWriter(oldWriter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To a certain degree where only a simple text is required Omnifaces `outputFormat` can save its output into a `var`.

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/outputFormat